# compare two model attributes in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I want to compare model attributes from my collection and store it to a new model.

```
Collection:
   Model1:
     Apple: 1
     Banana: 0
     Orange: 0
     Status: 1254869
   Model2:
     Apple: 0
     Banana: 1
     Orange: 1
     Status: null
```

The output should be:

```
ModelResult:
     Apple: 1
     Banana: 1
     Orange: 1
     Status: 1254869
```

Any ideas?

I'm doing it manually

```
ModelResult = collection.at(0); 
collection.each( function(model){
    if(model.get("Apple") != 0){
      ModelResult.set({Apple: model.get("Apple")});
    }
    if(model.get("Banana") != 0){
      ModelResult.set({Apple: model.get("Banana")});
    }
    if(model.get("Orange") != 0){
      ModelResult.set({Apple: model.get("Orange")});
    }
    if(model.get("Status") != ""){
      ModelResult.set({Apple: model.get("Status")});
    }
});
```

**NOTE:**

Is it possible to also eliminate `0` or `null` values on `ModelResult`?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you seen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically

Comment: Do you just want to compare if something is stored or would you want to compare the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For eliminating `0` and `null` values you can use [the `validate` function](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate). It is called always before `set` or `save` is called and if the valus don't match what you want you just return an error message and the changes won't take effect.

This also means your `ModelResult` has to be a separate model.

```
var ModelResult = Backbone.Model.extend({
  ...
  validate: function(attrs) {
    if (_.intersection([0, null], _.values(attrs))) {
      return "Zeroes and nulls are ignored.";
    }
  },
  ...
});
```

Now your each function could be like

```
function(model) {
  _.each(model.toJSON(), function(value, key) {
    ModelResult.set(key, value);
  }); 
}
```

Now all it will iterate through every model's every attribute and add them to the `ModelResult`, but filtering out all `0`s and `null`s.

Hope this helps!